# How do I create a tool in Python that can extract a sample from excel data?

Tags: python, excel, statistics, sampling

*This a complex problem that is hard for me to explain. Please let know if I need to explain anything further*

I want to create a tool in Python that can give me a sample using set parameters based on a large dataset. This dataset comes from an excel workbook. This problem is tricky because there are a lot of moving parts in the excel workbook that houses the data.

There are 8 excel sheets total in this workbook. 3 of the sheets are imported from an external database. 4 of the sheets were created to help rank the data (from the 3 imported sheets) into various categories. These 4 sheets total about 1,000,000 rows and up to 50 columns of data. The final sheet is used to create a 250-row sample using all 4 of the ranking sheets.  The way we get a sample is by having a weighting system with 5 parameters, and 5 corresponding weights. I also need to take into consideration that the 4 ranking sheets and the final sample sheet have multi-sheet reference formulas that tie back to the original 3 sheets; making this problem even more complex.

I am unsure how to tackle this problem. I'm thinking that I could somehow create a python sampling tool that references back to an excel workbook template I create. This template could have the 4 ranking sheets and the final sampling sheets, and all I would need to do is import that data from the external sources. The problem with this solution is that I'm trying to move away from excel, as these datasets can get quite large. However, I am unsure if I can accomplish such a complex task in Python without referencing an excel workbook.

Comment: If your excel file is not changing constantly, I would use pickle. You can quickly import pickle objects. This will save you a large chunk of time as you're testing or working on the project. [Pickle docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle). With pickling excel files, I think you could tackle this problem in python quite easily.

Comment: You might want to look into [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org)

Comment: My understanding is that there are 3 “steps”: 3 sheets as input; 4 sheets of “calculation”; 1 sheet as “summary”. If you do all the calculation part in Python (stored and processed as data frames) you don’t need the xls. If those 4 sheets’ contents still need to be accessible “externally”, you may want to store them as e.g. SQLite/duckDB. To keep the summary as xls sheet, Python can export it as xls after it’s done or Excel connects to your SQLite to show it as a xls sheet. (if interested in a low-code alternative to Python for your use case, you may want to have a look on KNIME)